# status bar hides when run code

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

For some reason whenever I run the code below in my app, the status bar disappears. I run in at the end of applicaitonLaunchOptions above return YES.

Does anyone know why this happens?

The code below asks people if they want to upgrade to new app version.

```
NSString * version = @"";
NSString * nstri = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=%@", APPID];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: nstri];

ASIFormDataRequest * versionRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[versionRequest setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
[versionRequest setDelegate:self];
[versionRequest setTimeOutSeconds:150];
[versionRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[versionRequest startSynchronous];

//Response string of our REST call
NSString* jsonResponseString = [versionRequest responseString];

NSDictionary *loginAuthenticationResponse = [jsonResponseString objectFromJSONString];

NSArray *configData = [loginAuthenticationResponse valueForKey:@"results"];

for (id config in configData)
{
    version = [config valueForKey:@"version"];
}

NSLog(@"app version: %@", version);

//Check your version with the version in app store
if (![version isEqualToString: APPVERSION])
{
    UIAlertView *createUserResponseAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Version!" message: @"A new version of Handybook app is available to download. Please update your app for the latest features." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"Download", nil];
    [createUserResponseAlert show];

}
```

Comment: Please don't do synchronous networking on the main thread! It makes me cry.

Answer (score 0):

could it be that you have this code in your AppDeleget.m in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *) launchOptions {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES with Animation:NO];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}
```

when yes the put out:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES with Animation:NO];
```

because that line of code hides the status bar